# Ionic: Viewing JSON objects of the product in woocommerce shopping site

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce

I am trying to view JSON objects of the products I have in my Woocommerce shopping site. And I keep getting this error
"**ionic.bundle.js:13438 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter.services due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'starter.services' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=starter.services**"

My app.js code is below:

```
 angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('app',{
    url: '/app',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
    abstract:true
  })
  .state('app.home',{
    url:'/home',
    views:{
      'menuContent' :{
        templateUrl:'templates/home.html',
        controller:'HomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, WC){
  var Woocommerce = WC.WC();
  Woocommerce.get('products/categories', function(err, data,res){
  console.log(res);

  })

})
.controller('HomeCtrl', function(){

})
```

My source looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
      // Injected Ionic Go To URL Live Reload Plugin
      window.LiveReloadPlugin_IonicGoToUrl = (function() {
        var GOTO_KEY = "__ionic_goto_url__";
        var HISTORY_GO_KEY = "__ionic_history_go__";
        var GoToUrlPlugin = function(window, host) {
          this.window = window;
          this.host = host;
        }
        GoToUrlPlugin.identifier = "__ionic_goto_url__";
        GoToUrlPlugin.version = "1.0";
        GoToUrlPlugin.prototype.reload = function(path) {
          try {
            if (path) {
              if (path.indexOf(GOTO_KEY) === 0) {
                this.window.document.location = path.replace(GOTO_KEY, "");
                return true;
              }
              if (path.indexOf(HISTORY_GO_KEY) === 0) {
                this.window.document.history.go( parseInt(path.replace(HISTORY_GO_KEY, ""), 10));
                return true;
              }
            }
          } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
          return false;
        };
        return GoToUrlPlugin;
      })();
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

   <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script>//<![CDATA[
document.write('<script src="//' + (location.hostname || 'localhost') + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"><\/script>')
//]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that a back tick (`)at the beginning of your code?

Comment: No module with that name shown here. What should it's source be?

Comment: Did you load the `starter.services` in your project? If so where?

Comment: @charlietfl I have uploaded the source code.

Comment: @VassilisPits service.js: `angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .service('WC', function() {
        return {
            WC: function() {
                var Woocommerce = new WooCommerceAPI.WooCommerceAPI({
                    url: 'woocom-barrackboy.c9users.io/',
                    consumerKey: 'ck_7f5251bda36d3f102423708857599e6c8bdb3664',
                    consumerSecret: 'cs_31aca6df8159bb0ee149164b97112f5cf0a37427'
                });
                return Woocommerce;
            }
        }
    });`